# Makefile.in Files Not Generated with Automake 1.12.2

Tags: autotools, automake

I recently upgraded my OS and upgraded my autotools versions with it. Now, one branch of my project will no longer build because automake no longer is using the Makefile.am files to generate the Makefile.in files. It is strange to me:

1. automake 1.11.6 works for the same branch.
2. automake 1.12.2 works for later branches, just not this branch. The major difference to the build process for the later branches is that they compile using g++ instead of gcc, although I don't see why that would affect this step of things.

Any ideas on where to look or how to track this down? I'm still very much finding my way in the world of autotools. My initial comparison of Makefile.am and configure.ac haven't led me towards anything promising. Obviously, I can put an older version of automake on this machine but I'm wondering if some underlying issue is affecting things here.

Comment: You probably need to start from the beginning.  Does whatever build step that invokes `autoreconf` (like a `bootstrap.sh` file) write a valid `configure`?  Does `configure` run?

Comment: It does create a valid configure file. The way I know that automake isn't working properly is that when I run configure it errors out saying it can't find Makefile.in files.

Comment: That's a big hint that `autoreconf` (or whatever invokes it) is not getting to the point where it's writing `Makefile.in` files.

Comment: @ldav1s good point. Now I feel like a dope. The answer was to fix the warnings from automake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ldav1s if you make that an answer I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Makefile.in` files are not being written, it's likely that either the bootstrap script (if there is one) or `autoreconf` is failing to write them.